# error message by list comprehension with floored float numbers and in lambda functions

Tags: function, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm learning Haskell and have some problems with list comprehension.
If I define a function to get a list of the divisors of a given number, I get an error.

```
check n = [x | x <- [1..(floor (n/2))], mod n x == 0]
```

I don't get why it's causing an error. If I want to generate a list from `1` to `n/2` I can do it with `[1..(floor (n/2))]`, but not if I do it in the list comprehension.

I tried another way but I get also an error (in this code I want to get all so called "perfect numbers")

```
f n = [1..(floor (n/2))]

main = print $ filter (\t -> foldr (+) 0 (f t) == t) [2..100]
```

Comment: Share the error message...

Comment: When I try this locally it works, while it is not most efficient way to do this, it will produce factors for `n`.

Comment: If you specified a type signature, please share that one as well, since for your `check`, `n` and the type of theitems will *not* be the same.

Comment: For me it also doesn’t give an error when I try it locally.

Comment: if i try to compile it i get 4 very big error messages. if i try to write it in the console i get:
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in `Data.Either'

Comment: @Herakles: your implemenntation requires `n` to be both a `RealFrac` and an `Integer`, so the compiler has no type to fill in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is better to start writing a signature. While signatures are often not required, it makes it easier to debug a single function.

The signature of your `check` function is:

```
check :: (RealFrac a, Integral a) => a -> [a]
```

The type of input (and output) `a` thus needs to be both a `RealFrac` and an `Integral`. While technically speaking we *can* make such type, it does not make much sense.

The reason this happens is because of the use of [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) this requires `x` and `n` to be both of the same type, and `a` should be a member of the `Integral` typeclass.

Another problem is the use of `n/2`, since [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) requires that `n` and `2` have the same type as `n / 2`, and `n` should also be of a type that is a member of `Fractional`. To make matters even worse, we use [**`floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor) which enforces that `n` (and thus `x` as well) have a type that is a member of the `RealFrac` typeclass.

We can prevent the `Fractional` and `RealFrac` type constaints by making use of [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) instead. Since `mod` already required `n` to have a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass, this thus will not restrict the types further:

```
check n = [x | x <- [1 .. div n 2], mod n x == 0]
```

This for example prints:

```
Prelude> print (check 5)
[1]
Prelude> print (check 17)
[1]
Prelude> print (check 18)
[1,2,3,6,9]
```

Comment: thank you for your help and detailed answer.